# Formatar data de tabela mysql e mostrar no Smarty

Tags: php, mysql, mvc, datetime, template

Estou desenvolvendo uma página em PHP, utilizando estrutura MVC e renderizando os arquivos de tamplete com o Smarty.

Porém estrou enfrentando uma dificuldade em obter uma data via MySQL(vê no formato: ANO-MÊS-DIA HORA:MINUTO:SEGUNDO

Eu gostaria que fosse apresentado no seguinte formado:
DIA/MÊS/ANO - HORA:MINUTO

Já consegui fazer para pegar os dados no MySQL, como mostra abaixo:

```
    $feed = new feedAction();
    $feedPostsSelect = $feed->select();
    $view->assign("feedList",$feedPostsSelect);

    $view->assign("textFeed", "text");
    $view->assign("usuarioFeed", "idauthor");
    $view->assign("publishDateFeed", "publishDate");
```

E no arquivo tpl:

```
{$row.publishDate}
```

Eu já tentei como em timestamp do smarty mostra, que seria:

```
{$smarty.now|date_format:"%d/%m/%Y - %H:%M"}
```

Porém utilizar o $row.publishDate|date_format não funciona, se quer exibe algum dado na tela.

Como prosseguir?

Obrigado pela atenção!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problema resolvido com sucesso!
Na query, onde vai os dados que serão puxado do banco de dados, é necessário pegar já formatado, ou seja, a query ficará:

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(T1.publishDate, '%%d/%%m/%%Y - %%H:%%i') AS publishDateFormated FORM tabela;
```

Embora ninguém ajudou até o momento, espero que minha própria resposta ajude alguém! :)